# Gitlab backup restore Error --> tar: This does not look like a tar archive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gitlab, backup

I am trying to restore GitLab (8.16.1) backup on Ubuntu server (backup taken by command `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create`) using command:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1493107454_2018_04_25_10.6.4-ce
```

Its giving me error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

my Backup file is **.tar** file.

gzip version 1.6

As of my knowledge before it restore that backup file it first extract.
I don't know why that extracted files are having extension `.tar.gz`.

Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1493107454_2018_04_25_10.6.4-ce
```

That means you should have a file like:

```
var/opt/gitlab/backups/1493107454_2018_04_25_10.6.4-ce_gitlab_backup.tar
```

And a `cat backup_information.yml` in that same folder giving you information about that backup.
If the file is not a valid archive, that would explain the error message.
You can add  `--trace` to the rake command to know more.

Comment: yes , I have .tar file at this location you said..Let me check it by doing --trace.

Comment: Hey @VonC, cat backup_information.yml giving an info about DB ,gitlab version(8.16.1) tar_version: tar(GNU tar) 1.28

Comment: @DarshanaPatel OK, and your current GitLab is of the same version, right? The tar is still 1.28 on your system?

Comment: yeah..GITLAB has the same version and tar 1.28

Comment: I don't have much more than https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md. Independently of the rake command, can you untar the archive, just to check it is a valid one?

Comment: yupp..I did this..and got files (artifacts.tar.gz  backup_information.yml  builds.tar.gz  db  lfs.tar.gz  repositories  uploads.tar.gz)

Comment: @DarshanaPatel Thant looks like a normal backup content. I see your command in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md#restore-for-omnibus-installations, for an omnibus installation. Is your GitLab an Omnibus one, or one installed from sources?

Comment: Its Omnibus one @VonC